# What is the "sniffer" process in Activity Monitor?

Tags: macos, packet-sniffers

My computer (Mac running OS 10.8.5) was getting slow so I checked my Activity Monitor, and found that the top process, taking up 99-100.6% of my CPU, is called "sniffer". Any idea what this is?

PID: 2596
Process Name: sniffer
% CPU: 100.0
Threads: 2
Real Memory: 3.3MB
Kind: Intel (64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

find the process id in Activity monitor.  for instance 275

then in terminal

ps -axwww | grep 275

which should give you the path to the executable.

Comment: Thanks. I've since stopped the process and rebooted the computer, and haven't seen the process pop up again yet (it's been about 6 hours of use since then). I will try running this command if/when the process comes back.